# Permission denied when trying to open a file with FileManager (Swift 3)

Tags: swift

Not sure this is a problem with my code, but I'm getting a "permission denied" error advising I don't have permission to view the file/folder while executing the `let files = try fileManager(...)` line.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Volumes/Worktop/Telemetry/", isDirectory: true)

do {
    let resourceKeys:[URLResourceKey] = [.fileSizeKey]
    let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)

    for file in files
    {
        if file.pathExtension == "ibt"
        {
            print(file.absoluteString)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The attributes are set to `read/write` for both the files and the folder, so I don't think this is the problem. Any pointers or help on how to access the files from code is appreciated.

Comment: Is sandboxing enabled in your project?

Comment: It is, and in the `File Access` section the `User Selected File` field is set to `Read Only`. Do I need to change any of these?

Comment: Yes, if you plan to access files outside your Application's files, you will have to disable Sandboxing. For more information, see the [AppSandbox DesignGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html)

Comment: ...and it was that easy. Thanks, and thanks for the link.